# metafor - How to extract the F-statistic

Tags: metafor

Just a short question:

I am doing a meta-analysis using the `metafor` package and I am using the rma.mv function for a 3-level model. How do I extract the f-statistic for the moderator analysis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some strategies for figuring out the answer to this:

1. Look at the documentation for the function and in particular, the `Value` section that describes what the function returns. For `rma.mv()`, see here:

   https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/rma.mv.html#value-1

   The F-statistic you are asking about is presumably the one from the omnibus test. Looking through the section, we find `QM - test statistic of the omnibus test of moderators.`
2. Alternatively, one can examine the object that is returned by the function directly. The `str()` function is quite useful for this, so just do `str(model)`. There is a lot of stuff that is returned by the function (not all of which is documented in the `Value` section described above) and you are essentially just looking for the element that appears to contain the value you are looking for. You can go even further and use `unclass(model)`, which strips the class from the object and just prints the list as is. Same idea though - just look through what is returned for the element that contains the F-statistic. After some searching, you will find again that this is contained in element `QM`.

So, `model$QM` will give you the F-statistic.